# How do I input a positive number and prints out the square roots up to the number entered?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble finding the sqrt roots for a number. my assignment is to Write a program that prompts the user for a positive number and prints out the square roots of all the numbers from 1 to the entered number.
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
double x;
int i;

cout <<"Enter how many numbers you wish to process:";
cin >> x;

for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)

cout<< sqrt(x);

}
```

the problem I have is that I can only find the sqrt of the number I inputted 4 times and not to that number. my output comes out at 2222.
i need my output to look like this

```
Enter how many numbers you wish to process: 4
1: 1
2: 1.41421
3: 1.73205
4: 2
```

Comment: change `sqrt(x)` to `sqrt(i)`

Answer (score 3):

You're getting exactly what you asked for:

```
cout<< sqrt(x);
```

That's the square root of `x`, which you've said was 4, ergo the answer is 2 always. You want `i`.

Comment: my output comes out to this if i have cout<<sqrt(i)  Enter how many numbers you wish to process:4                 11.414211.732052

Comment: @john315 1, 1.414, 1.72305, 2 are correct. You have no space between your prints.

Comment: how would i go about spacing out my sqrts?

Comment: Add `<< std::endl` at the end for a newline. If you need a refresher on how to use the C++ input and output streams, would be good to dig up a reference on how they work. It's not super complicated.

Comment: @john315 Print some spaces and/or newlines before or after each one?